# How to Logout from Firebase Account to Login Screen from Fragment

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

My idea is to log out of the firebase account through a fragment, i.e. on the icon in the navigation menu (which is below), the active account is logged out and the login activity is switched to. I did it, but it doesn’t work the way I wanted, that is, the exit occurs after switching to the fragment and you need to click on the icon again. And when you press the back button on your smartphone, it opens the previous activity that was, how to remove it? The code which is in the fragment:

```
View exit;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        exit = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.exit);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(ExitFragment.this.getParentFragment().getActivity(), MainActivityEntrance.class));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Screenshot of navigation menu:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x3rs.png)

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, I think you're looking for a splash screen. That being said, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) might help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).